# chromedriver works but "phantomjs unable to locate item using css selector"

Tags: phantomjs, nightwatch.js

I'm designing some end to end testing for my job, and I've got it up and running using nightwatch.js through chromedriver. However, we're looking to have this run on our servers, and so I wanted to be able to run it using phantomjs. Although the test performs without incident using chromedriver, Phantomjs yields the following error "phantomjs unable to locate item using css selector"

Any ideas? I've scoured the internet for a solution, to no avail.

Answer (score 5):

First, check **decates**' comment here: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/243#issuecomment-94287511

See how depending on the user-agent info passed from your browser to the site, the site returns different XHTML data? So if you want to use phantomjs, but are okay with it spoofing as a different browser via the user agent, you can configure phantomjs' user-agent capabilities, like this (spoofing Mac Chrome):

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
  "browserName": "phantomjs",
  "phantomjs.cli.args" : ["--ignore-ssl-errors=true"],
  "phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"
}
```

Then your tests should act the same as your other browser. Using any browser you like, you can check the user-agent string that it sends here: http://www.httpuseragent.org/. Here are some other examples:

```
// Mac Chrome 46
"phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"

// Windows Chrome 46
"phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"

// Mac Firefox 42.0
"phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"

// Windows Firefox 42.0
"phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"

// PhantomJS 2.0
"phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.0.0 Safari/538.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes have this effect in the difference browsers, not only phantoms. The reason seemed to be that elements are not loaded at the time of evaluating for one browser (and are loaded for another). You can debug it with checking screenshots at the point of failure.

The solution for me was using waitForElementPresent/Visible.