# Nightwatch test passes in chrome but not phantomjs

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, nightwatch.js

I have simple test:

```
module.exports = {
  'can view and click regions from dropdown': function(client) {
    var home = client.page.home();

    home.navigate().waitForElementVisible('body', 5000)

    home.expect.element('@title').to.be.present;
    home.expect.element('@title').text.to.contain('React Redux Example');

    home.expect.element('@regionDropdown').to.be.present;
    client.getText('.navbar-nav', function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    });

    home.expect.element('@regionDropdown').text.to.contain('Explore');

    home.moveToElement('@regionDropdown', 5, 5, function(response) {
      home.expect.element('@popover').to.be.present;

      home.moveToElement('@popover', 5, 5, function(response) {
        home.expect.element('@popover').to.be.present;
      });

      client.expect.element('.navbar-brand').to.be.present;

      client.moveToElement('.navbar-brand', 0, 0, function(response) {
        home.waitForElementNotPresent('@popover', 1000);
      });
    });

    client.end();
  }
}
```

Which passes in chrome just fine, but when running phantomjs 2.0, it finds no content in the `navbar-nav li:first-child a` let alone in the whole `.navbar-nav`. It finds the element, but no test.

Thoughts?

My config:

```
{
  "src_folders": ["tests/functional/specs"],
  "page_objects_path": ["tests/functional/pages"],
  "output_folder": "tests/functional/output",
  "custom_commands_path": "tests/functional/commands",
  "custom_assertions_path": "tests/functional/assertions",
  "globals_path": "tests/functional/globals.js",
  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "node_modules/selenium-server/lib/runner/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 5555,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver"
    }
  },
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "exclude": ["./pages", "./commands"],
      "filter": "*.spec.js",
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port" : 5555,
      "selenium_host" : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "path" : "tests/functional/screenshots"
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },
    "production" : {
      "exclude": ["./pages", "./commands"],
      "filter": "*.spec.js",
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port" : 5555,
      "selenium_host" : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "path" : "tests/functional/screenshots"
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName" : "phantomjs",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts" : true,
        "phantomjs.binary.path" : "/usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs"
      }
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

PhantomJS presents a different default user agent than Chrome. Your issue might be that your server is returning different data based on the user agent that it sees.

In your PhantomJS desiredCapabilities, you might try passing in a "phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" setting that matches your browser's user agent setting and see if it makes any difference.

See more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33618363/3043369

Good luck!